# Using an XML stream from existing program

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am not sure about a lot of this, so Google and other research has been a little confusing. So I came here.

There is an existing program, we'll call it Program A. It generates XML files.
The program I am making will be a part of this existing Program A (via a dll I think), we'll call mine Program B.

When using Program A, users' actions will either result in: Opening existing XML files or creating a new one. After pressing a particular button in Program A, Program B will be opened up which will be passed the information from the XML file that the user has open in Program A. An XML Stream.

I understand this, and I can create the rest of Program B just fine so far. It is actually capturing the information from Program A that I am completely lost on, the information that is to be passed to Program B so I can then work with it.

I have no trouble reading and writing to XML files, my trouble is figuring out what to code to accept the XML stream from Program A. Is there some documentation on this, tips, hints? Anything would help.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can't access any of the code for Program A or a vast majority of it's assets and inner workings. Only parts of it to get my program to work.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You need to ask for more details. Ask them how the data are to be passed from program a to program b, and what kind of "program" program B is meant to be.

Comment: Program B is just a windows form that can manipulate the data passed to it, and write new/changed data back to the same XML file it came from. As far as I know right now, there is a process in place in Program A that passes the XML stream to my program. That's all I have been told so far. I was not sure if there is a way to nab that information being passed, sort of in a similar way as if a Console App were to be passed parameters. A lot of new stuff for me on this one.

Comment: Any answer you might be given will depend on the details of how program A passes "the XML stream" to your program. You must go find out first. There is no single standard way to do this.